# Package application dependencies into native AIR installer windows

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe

I have an AIR application that I'm trying to package with another piece of software that requires an installation itself (Windows). Is it possible to package a separate installation file and create a combined installer that would install the dependency application first?

I know http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air3-install-and-deployment-options.html says you can package MSI files together to create MSM modules but I do not have an MSI file, only an .exe.

Comment: To be honest I've never packed an msi along with AIR, BUT it's easy to convert exe to msi. Search Google for such tools, they are free! :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov thanks, I will check out converting to an MSI

Comment: I use a Captive Runtime for my AIR application which gets installed via a MSI package. You have the same opportunities as you have with an exe file.

Comment: @PaulFacklam I thought captive runtime was for bundling air into you application to avoid a download at runtime. Can you include 3rd party apps into the captive runtime?